# LINQ and checking if strings in an array exist in a SQL field

Tags: c#, sql, linq

In my SQL database one of the columns is titled "description". The user basically writes a paragraph and this is stored in the db. I want to extract any word in that paragraph that represents a fruit. So I have an array called

```
 fruit = {"apple", "orange", "pineapple", "lime", etc.}
```

Is there an easy way to use LINQ to select amy fruit (based om the fruit array) that might exist in the text stored in the description field.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help to show a class model. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the class containing the `Description` field is `Products`, here is how to get the ones that their description contains one of the fruits:

```
Product[] results = Products.Where(item => fruit.Any(q=> item.Contains(q))).ToArray();
```

For getting all the fruits in the description as you mentioned in the comments, its even easier:

```
string[] results = fruit.Where(f=> description.Contains(f)).Select(r => r).ToArray();
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7B0a1W)

Comment: Thanks Ashkan...not exactly what i was after though. Say in row 1 of the Products table in the description field there is the following text: "I bought an apple, and then I ate an orange, and then I went and bought a lemon". And there is an array of fruit = {apple, orange, lemon, pineapple, watermelon}. I specifically want to extract the fruit just from this particular field so in the end i have string[] result = {"apple", "orange", "lemon"}. I don't need to do it for every description field in the Product table. Just for a single description field that I specify. Thanks

Comment: so this must select it three times you mean?

Comment: sorry, i just edited the question. does it make sense now?

Comment: one description and select all fruits? or all fruits from all descriptions?

Comment: one description and select all fruits. yeah. thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I also added a demo. please have a look.